# Here is a simple XSD+XML example. How to make the validation work?

Tags: xml, xsd

I have an XSD with two defined types and a simple XML to validate against. The error message is

`src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'colorType' to a(n) 'type definition' component`

and there are several questions with that error message, but the circumstances seem to be others. Also the example documents are usually big and I have problems seeing the relevant parts. So here is a simple one.

XSD (named `svg_export_test.xsd`):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  targetNamespace="test"
  attributeFormDefault="unqualified" 
  elementFormDefault="qualified">

<xs:element name="colorType">
  <xs:simpleType>
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:pattern value="#[0-9A-Fa-f]{8}"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="clothingType">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="color" type="colorType" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

XML (named `svg_export_test.xml` in the same folder):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<t:clothingType xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xs:schemaLocation="svg_export_test.xsd"
  xmlns:t="test"
  >
  <t:name>Shirt</t:name>
  <t:color>#00000000</t:color>
</t:clothingType>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you've said `type="colorType"`, but `colorType` isn't a type, it's an element declaration. You need an `<xs:simpleType name="colorType">` at the top level of your schema for this to work.

Secondly, if you add this, the type `colorType` will be in namespace `test`, so to refer to it, you need to use `type="t:colorType"`, where the namespace prefix `t` is bound to the namespace `test` (add `xmlns:t="test"` to your `xs:schema` element)

The corrected XSD would then be

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  targetNamespace="test" xmlns:t="test"
  attributeFormDefault="unqualified" 
  elementFormDefault="qualified">

<xs:simpleType name="colorType">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
    <xs:pattern value="#[0-9A-Fa-f]{8}"/>
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>

<xs:element name="clothingType">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="color" type="t:colorType" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

Comment: I added the working version to your post. Once the edit is approved, I can accept the answer.